# nginx infinite loop with try_files and index

Tags: nginx

using the following config for Nginx, I'm noticing I get an infinite loop of location processing.  Based on my understanding from the docs, I'd expect a request to `http://localhost:8080` to simply return my `index.html` file based on my `index` directive.  Instead the request maps to `location /` in a loop, appending a / each time, based on what I can see from my X-debug header.  The output from my debugging message is:

`X-debug-one:location / /////////// /var/www/content`

As you can see, the $uri keeps growing for a few iterations.  What's the point of the index directive if it isn't respected?  I would expect the index to be tested at some point in the process?

Here's my config.  I must be missing something obvious here.  Just a note, this is running from inside a Docker container, with port mapping to 8080.

```
server {
  server_name _;
  listen 80 default_server;

  root /var/www/content;
  index index.html;

  access_log /dev/stdout;
  error_log /dev/stdout info;

  add_header X-debug-base "base $uri $document_root" always;

  location / {
    add_header X-debug-one "location / $uri $document_root" always;
    try_files $uri $uri/;
  }
}
```

Edit:

Here's the response from curl (curl -sSL -D - "localhost:8080" -o /dev/null)  from both outside Docker (localhost:8080), and inside docker (localhost:80)

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: nginx/1.10.3
Date: Sat, 06 Jan 2018 22:55:35 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 193
Connection: close
X-debug-one: location / /////////// /var/www/content
```

Here are the logs, capturing my curl and I think there's a Chrome request there too.

```
unyozi_1    | 2018-01-06 22:57:23,869 DEBG 'nginx' stdout output:
unyozi_1    | 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Jan/2018:22:57:23 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 193 "-" "curl/7.52.1"
unyozi_1    | 
unyozi_1    | 2018-01-06 22:57:37,722 DEBG 'nginx' stdout output:
unyozi_1    | 2018/01/06 22:57:37 [error] 11#0: *13 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "////////////", client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
unyozi_1    | 
unyozi_1    | 2018-01-06 22:57:37,722 DEBG 'nginx' stdout output:
unyozi_1    | 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Jan/2018:22:57:37 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 193 "-" "curl/7.52.1"
unyozi_1    | 
unyozi_1    | 2018-01-06 22:58:43,546 DEBG 'nginx' stdout output:
unyozi_1    | 2018/01/06 22:58:43 [error] 11#0: *14 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/sockjs-node/info///////////", client: 172.19.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /sockjs-node/info?t=1515279507454 HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/"
unyozi_1    | 
unyozi_1    | 2018-01-06 22:58:43,547 DEBG 'nginx' stdout output:
unyozi_1    | 172.19.0.1 - - [06/Jan/2018:22:58:43 +0000] "GET /sockjs-node/info?t=1515279507454 HTTP/1.1" 500 595 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36"
unyozi_1    |
```

Edit 2: /var/www/content/index.html is a file that exists.

Comment: Best guess: the problem isn't with your Nginx config, it's somewhere else. Check your file permissions, that the user the web server runs as can access the files.

Comment: @Tim I made sure www-data:www-data is the owner for the entire file hierarchy.  However, I don't think permissions is the issue anyways, since localhost:8080/index.html returns the content as expected.  At this point, I guess this must be expected behaviour from try_files?  Most examples I see include a specific termination point of the index file, like so:  $uri $uri/ /index.html.  Just bothers me that this is somewhat counter to my expectation based on the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
    try_files $uri $uri/;
```

Adding a `/` to the end of an argument in `try_files` causes it to try that URL with the paths specified in the `index` directive, in your case `index.html`.

When you load `/`, try_files first tries `$uri`, which doesn't match, then it gets to `$uri/` and tries `/index.html`, which re-enters the same `location` block. Because `index.html` doesn't exist, it gets to `$uri/` again, goes back to try `/index.html` again, re-enters the `location` block, and gives you the `rewrite or internal redirection cycle` error.

To fix this, specify a reasonable default for when a static file is not found in your `try_files`. If you have a static-only site, this could be `=404`. If you are going to run a web app, then it could be a location for that app. For example:

```
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;        # Static site
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;  # PHP front controller
    try_files $uri $uri/ @uwsgi;      # pass to a named location
```

Comment: Edited my question to clarify that index.html exists at /var/www/content/.  Perhaps as Tim says, it is a permission issue that index.html isn't available to nginx?

Comment: came back to this and re-read your answer.  I understand now that `index.html` doesn't exist as a *location* in the config, and hence it recycles.  makes sense!  Thanks for the thorough answer.